# Preview development R documentation

Tags: r, documentation, devtools, roxygen2

I'm writing my first R Package using `devtools` and `roxygen2` in the RStudio IDE. The problem I have is related with previewing the .Rd files I get when I "roxygenize" the .R files. I'm using `devtools::document()` in order to get the .Rd files, but when I try to preview the Help Pages by writing any of:

```
help("FunctionName")
?FunctionName
```

the console shows the message "Using development documentation for..." but there's a blank space in the help window.  Using `devtools:load_all()` causes the same problem. Maybe this is related with the way `devtools` loads the package in the environment, but neither the document "Writing R Extensions" (that isn't expected to be consulted to use `roxygen`), nor the book "R packages" by Hadley Wickham provides a working solution.

Comment: Does it work after building?

Comment: If I generate the documentation, build the .tar file, install it and library the package there's still the same problem. I usually close and reopen RStudio to make things work. However, this is a really tedious task to just preview the .Rd files.

Comment: @Servadac Do you still have this issue?

Comment: The solution I've found is Built & Reload the package , with the RStudio button, what needs more time and is not as useful to debug the code. When I write this question I didn't know that RStudio has this capability.

Answer (score 5):

In Rstudio under *project options* there is a *generate documentation with roxygen item* - check it.

[image]

Then click on *Configure...* and check the boxes like that:

[image]

Now, each time you hit Ctrl+Shift+B your doc files will be rebuild and you can browse them via clicking on the function name and hitting F1 or typing one of the following lines in the console:

```r
?my_function
help(my_function)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it through code and not GUI? Thanks